# A fast method for calculating the probabilities of items in a distribution using python

Tags: python, dictionary, probability

Is there a quick method or a function than automatically computes probabilities of items in a distribution without importing random?

For instance, consider the following distribution (dictionary):

```
y = {"red":3, "blue":4, "green":2, "yellow":5}
```

1. I would like to compute the probability of picking each item.
2. I would also like to compute the probability of picking a red and two greed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you mean:  y={"red":3, "blue":4, "green":2, "yellow":5}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the frequencies:

```
   y = {"red":3, "blue":4, "green":2, "yellow":5} 
   frequencies = {key:float(value)/sum(y.values()) for (key,value) in y.items()}
```

And the probabilities of having a given combination is the probability of each of them multiplied by the previous ones.

```
   combination = ["red", "green", "green"]
   prob = 1. # initialized to 1
   for ii in combination:
       prob *= frequencies[ii]
   print prob
   0.00437317784257
```

Does that sound reasonable?